# Did Chrome break svg stroke='url(#...)'?

Tags: url, google-chrome, svg, fill, stroke

In early December I put up a web page developed in Chrome using HTML tables with fancy borders created with SVG.  Because the table cell size is unknown, I must use relative (%) coordinates to get to the bottom and right borders.  Therefore I must use line elements.  I can fill those lines with a pattern using the stroke='url(#...)' method, where the ... is a pattern element in the local defs section.  This is no longer working in Chrome, but is in Safari and Firefox.  The very similar fill='url(#...)' is working in Chrome, but I cannot use it with relative anchor coordinates.

Anybody run into this?

Here is a test case:

```
<svg patternUnits='userSpaceOnUse' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' 
xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' version='1.1'>

<defs>
    <pattern id='utrim' height='10' width='10' patternUnits='userSpaceOnUse' >
                <rect height='10' width='5' fill='green' />
    </pattern>

    <pattern id='utrim2' height='10' width='10' patternUnits='userSpaceOnUse' >
                <rect height='10' width='5' fill='red' />
    </pattern>

</defs>

<g > 
    <line x1='0' y1='0' x2='100%' y2='0' stroke-width='20' stroke='url(#utrim)' />
    <rect x='0' y='0' width='100%' height='5' fill='url(#utrim2)' />
</g> 

</svg>
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe a little late, but pure horizontal lines fail to use urls.
You may use a small offset to overcome this:

```
<line x1='0' y1='0' x2='100%' y2='0.01' stroke-width='20' stroke='url(#utrim)' />
```

Answer (score 1):

Well I've reported this to Chromium.

I figured out how to work around this with filled rectangles. I can position the rectangle just past the lower and right edges of the viewport, pull them back with a transform='translate(...)', and fill them with the pattern.  The pattern aligns to the dimensions of the space it is filling, which I did not realize, and which makes everything work the way I need it to.

Answer (score 0):

As of chrome 72 '#' signifies the end of a uri. https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5656049583390720

Comment: And the full thread discussing why they removed it https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=123004